# Apply formatting to an Excel file programmatically

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want to format an existing Excel file (xls) cell in such a way that the cell values in a column only show two digits after the decimal.

So instead of `0.090919729581319146%`, I want to show `0.09%`.

I need to do this across multiple documents, so I need some repeatable way to apply the transformation. I was thinking of a macro - and tried it with the integrated macro recorder in Excel 2010, but unfortunately couldn't get it to work.

I have only to format a Range from C3 --> C5000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something on web. Look at this code. It does what i am talking about:

```
Sub NurZumUeben()
With Range("C2:C5000")
    .Replace What:="%", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
        Range ("K1") = 100
        Range ("K1").Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste :=xlPasteAll, Operation:= xlDivide
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        Range("K1").Clear
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post *images* of code as solutions. They're impossible to copy to use for testing or correction (or for someone else to use as a solution). If you want to post the code, post it as actual code. Thanks.